# LINQ TO SQL GRR! How to map this inheritance?

Tags: linq-to-sql

Hi I am having trouble with mapping an inheritance at runtime (inserting rows to DB, I get an error about the properties belonging to the superclass & nt the subclass. i have a few properties i only want to define in the superclass, so that all the subclasses can inherit them in a DRY manner.

I'm happy for the superclass to be instantiated and have a record added to the DB when its subclass is.

So my question is how do I map this without getting an error? E.G

```
[Table]
[InheritanceMapping(Code = "CJ", Type = typeof(CronJob))]
[InheritanceMapping(Code = "SCJ", Type = typeof(SongCronJob))]
public class CronJob { 
[Column(Name = "name")] /* I want this to be inherited by subclasses */
public string name { get; set; }
}

[Table]
public class SongCronJob { }
```

But because it wasn't defined in SongCronJob, when I try to insert a SongCronJob into DB it errors! :-/!

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have your class SongCronJob decorated with the TableAttribute.
The only table you have is CronJob.

and you need to declare your SongCronJob as:

`public class SongCronJob : CronJob { }`

I think that will solve your problem.